# Table of content don't show a number for a line

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, line-numbering

I'm new to Latex and I'm writing my thesis with "report" document class.
These are my first lines:

```
...
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage}

\begin{document} 

\includepdf{cover.pdf}
\afterpage{\blankpage}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
text text text

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{Roman}   
text text text

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
text text text
```

Essentially quite all is good:
"Abstract" and table of contents are unnumbered, "Introduction" is numbered with Roman numbers and "Chapter1" with arabic numbers.

Unfortunately in table of contents the line "Introduction" has no number near it. I'd like it shows the roman 'I' number (that's the right number).

Comment: you switch to Roman too late, after you have written the table of contents line.

Comment: Putting Roman after \tableofcontent I obtain what I wanted, but now the last page of the table of content is numbered 'I' so the "Introduction" starts with 'II'. That's so curious since in the table of contents "Introduction" line shows number 'I'...

Comment: change of pagenumbering should always be after a forced pagebreak so `\clearpage` normally.

Comment: also it's not clear why you have `\afterpage` or `\blankpage`  the `\pagenumbering` resets the page counter to 1 so the subtracting of one in `\blankpage` isn't doing anything.

Comment: I solved putting \clearpage after \tableofcontents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing page numbering the normal sequence is

```
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
```

so the existing page gets finished with the old scheme but the new numbering is in place before you write the table of contents line.